# Receiving Firebase Cloud Messaging without Notification alert in ios

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, swift4.2

I followed a lot of instructions, I can receive the fcm message (log captured below) from HTTP legacy with device token but none triggered a notification alert...
App Settings Notification is on. All permissions granted.

Currently I'm using AppDelegate.swift code from [tutsplus](https://github.com/tutsplus/get-started-with-firebase-messaging-for-ios/blob/master/Firebase-FCM/AppDelegate.swift)

```
Message ID: 15629416****347211
[AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 15629416****347211, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert =     {
        body = "body-test";
        title = "title-test";
    };
}]
```

Comment: Is it going thought APNS?

Comment: sure... I know it, the app receive the message but not show it